# Implementing binary search in javascript

Tags: javascript, binary-search

I am trying to implement binary search in javascript. I don't know what is going wrong with my script. The page becomes unresponsive whenever I click the search button.Thanks in advance.

```js
var i,print,arr;
 arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
 print = document.getElementById("showArray");
 for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  print.innerHTML += arr[i] + "&nbsp;"; 
 }
 function binarySearch(searchValue){ 
   var lowerIndex, higherIndex, middleIndex,writeResult;
   lowerIndex = 0;
   higherIndex = arr.length;
   writeResult = document.getElementById("showResult");
   while(lowerIndex <= higherIndex){
     middleIndex = (higherIndex + lowerIndex) / 2;
  if(searchValue == arr[middleIndex]){
    writeResult.innerHTML = "PRESENT";
    consol.log('Present');
    break;
  }
  else if(searchValue > arr[middleIndex]){
    lowerIndex = middleIndex + 1;
  }
  else if(searchValue < arr[middleIndex]){
    higherIndex = middleIndex - 1;
  }
   }
 }
```

```html
<button onclick = "binarySearch(1)">SEARCH</button>
 <p id = "showArray" style = "font-size: 40px; padding:0px;">       </p>
 <p id = "showResult">Result is:</p>
```

Comment: Probably an infinite loop.  Just put something like `console.log(lowerIndex, higherIndex)` at the beginning of your loop and you'll see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
Array.prototype.br_search = function (target)   
{  
  var half = parseInt(this.length / 2);  
  if (target === this[half])   
  {  
    return half;  
  }  
  if (target > this[half])   
  {  
    return half + this.slice(half,this.length).br_search(target);  
  }   
  else  
  {  
    return this.slice(0, half).br_search(target);  
  }  
};  

l= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];  

console.log(l.br_search(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem, you have is not to use the integer part of the calculation for the `middleIndex`. This makes it impossible to check for a value at a given index of the array, because the index must be an integer number.

```js
var i,
    print = document.getElementById("showArray"),
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    print.innerHTML += arr[i] + "&nbsp;";
}

function binarySearch(searchValue) {
    var lowerIndex = 0,
        higherIndex = arr.length - 1,
        middleIndex,
        writeResult = document.getElementById("showResult");

    while (lowerIndex <= higherIndex) {
        middleIndex = Math.floor((higherIndex + lowerIndex) / 2);
        if (searchValue == arr[middleIndex]) {
            writeResult.innerHTML = "PRESENT " + middleIndex;
            break;
        }
        if (searchValue > arr[middleIndex]) {
            lowerIndex = middleIndex + 1;
        } else {
            higherIndex = middleIndex - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="binarySearch(2)">SEARCH</button>
<p id="showArray" style="font-size: 40px; padding:0px;">       </p>
<p id="showResult">Result is:</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

An iterative example of binary search without `break`.

Running time: `log2(n)`

```js
function search(array, target) {
  let min = array[0]
  let max = array.length - 1;
  let guess;
  
  while (max >= min) {
    guess = Math.floor((min+max)/2);
    if (array[guess] === target) {
      return guess;
    } else if (array[guess] > target) {
      max = guess - 1;
    } else {
      min = guess + 1;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

const primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];
console.log(search(primes, 67));
```